# Conflicting Keyboard Shortcuts in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I use Aptana Studio for PHP development. I also use the Emacs+ plugin in Eclipse to get an Emacs-like experience in the editor. However, when I try to use certain shortcuts, I get a pop-up from which I have to select which command to execute. For example, when I issue <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>, I a pop-up like so: (Oops, I don't have enough reputation to post an image!)

```
-----------------------------------
| Comment Line / Selection  |  1  |
|---------------------------------|
| Undo+                     |  2  |
-----------------------------------
```

This is quite annoying when I have to do a series of undo-s.

I would like to execute the commands bound by the Emacs+ plugin in such situations. I was thinking these were conflicts, but the Keys preferences window (Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys) does not show any. Any pointers to how I should go about achieving this?

Comment: Did the answer given below work?

Comment: Not really. I tried setting the **When:** drop-down to _Aptana Editor_ and _PHP Source Editing_. It didn't work in either case. I feel this should have worked with the default setting of _Editing Text_ too as there were no conflicts (at least none came up in the **Conflicts:** box).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys or Ctrl+Shift+L

and then go to the Command you are looking for.

Here you should be able to see the **Binding** and **When** drop downs.

[image]

For the same binding you can define different scopes.

Probably for Aptana you can define `PHP` scope (When dropdown).

I faced the same issue with Ctrl+Shift+T after installing Pydev. It used to bind to both *Open Type* and *Python Class Browser*. Changed the scope and it worked fine.